# Function Not working correctly on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, it works correctly on Chrome but not on Firefox and IE, what am I doing wrong?

```
$('.bookmarkbutton').on('click',function(){
 var pos = $(window).scrollTop();

 $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href'),           
        success: function(response) {             
        $.cookie('scroll', pos);
        location.reload(current_page);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mate , replace the code  location.reload(current_page); with this

```
history.go(0);
```

or

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

location.reload is known issue for firefox and ie.

Comment: ok but I want to reload the page to a url stored in the current_page variable and also go back to the position of that clicked button and it is not doing that.